# ERROR CANT FIND SYMBOL (FOR LOOP)

Tags: java, jvm, initialization, void, declare

Whenever i run this program, it says that it can't find the symbol for SHOTS (last line) , so I think the problem is because i am declaring the SHOTS inside the FOR LOOP, but when I wanted to print it out, I cant..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Hello, what's your name?");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Would you like to order some coffee, " + name + "? (y/n)");
        String goon=keyboard.next();
        char answer=goon.charAt(0);
        if ((answer!= 'y') && (answer!='n'))
            System.out.println("no valid");
        else if (answer== 'n')
            System.out.println("OK BYE");
        else {
            System.out.println("Great, Let's get started.");
            System.out.println("Order selection");
            System.out.println("----------------");
            System.out.println("There are 90 coffee cups in stock and each costs $2.00");
            System.out.println("There are 100 coffee shots in stock and each costs $1.00");
            System.out.println("How many cups of coffee would you like?");
            int CupsOfCoffee = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (CupsOfCoffee ==0)
                System.out.println("No cups, no coffee, Goodbye");
            else if (CupsOfCoffee < 0)
                System.out.println("Doesn't compute, system terminating");
            else if (CupsOfCoffee >90)
                 System.out.println("Not enogh stock,come back later");
            else {
                int countd;
                for (countd = 1; countd<= CupsOfCoffee; countd++) {
                    System.out.println("How many coffee shots in cup "+ countd);
                     int shots = keyboard.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println("Order Suammery\n----------------");
                for (countd = 1; countd<= CupsOfCoffee; countd++)
                    System.out.println("cup " + countd + "has" + shots+  "and will cost" ) ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to do some changes , by declaring the SHOTS outside the FOR LOOP, and i came up with that, by getting my output (SHOTS) the last number I enter: for example when I they ask how many shots, I say 2,3,4,.. all the cups (1,2 and 3) got 4 shots, which i want to get 2 shots for cup1, 3 shots for cup 2, and 4 shots for cup 3.. thats an example

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class CoffeeBot
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println ("Hello, what's your name?");
String name = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Would you like to order some coffee, " + name + "? (y/n)");
 String goon=keyboard.next();
 char answer=goon.charAt(0);  
 if ((answer!= 'y') && (answer!='n'))
 System.out.println("no valid");
 else if (answer== 'n')
 System.out.println("OK BYE");
else{
System.out.println("Great, Let's get started.");
 System.out.println("Order selection");
 System.out.println("----------------");
  System.out.println("There are 90 coffee cups in stock and each costs $2.00");
  System.out.println("There are 100 coffee shots in stock and each costs $1.00");
   System.out.println("How many cups of coffee would you like?");
   int CupsOfCoffee = keyboard.nextInt();
   if (CupsOfCoffee ==0)
   System.out.println("No cups, no coffee, Goodbye");
  else if (CupsOfCoffee < 0)
  System.out.println("Doesn't compute, system terminating");
  else if (CupsOfCoffee >90)
     System.out.println("Not enogh stock,come back later");
    else {


   int countd;
   int shots=0;
     for (countd = 1; countd<= CupsOfCoffee; countd++)
   {
      System.out.println("How many coffee shots in cup "+ countd);

     shots = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
   System.out.println("Order Suammery\n----------------");
    for (countd = 1; countd<= CupsOfCoffee; countd++)

   System.out.println("cup " + countd + "has" + shots+  "and will cost" ) ;

   }
   }
   }
   }
```

I think I should store the SHOTS values in an int[] array.

Comment: Is there something wrong with your shift key? ;-) You can pretty-print keywords by enclosing them with backticks (`\``)

Comment: ENOUGH WITH THE SHOUTING ALREADY PEOPLE ARE TRYING TO SLEEP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems. Firstly, in the println statement on the last line, you're referring to `shot` rather than `shots`.

Secondly, declaring `shots` outside the `for` loop is fine, but you're then redefining it inside the loop, hiding the other variable.

To use an array, try something like:

```
...
int[] shots = new int[CupsOfCoffee];
for (countd = 0; countd < CupsOfCoffee; countd++)
{
    System.out.println("How many coffee shots in cup " + (countd + 1));

    shots[countd] = keyboard.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Order Suammery\n----------------");
for (countd = 0; countd < CupsOfCoffee; countd++)

System.out.println("cup " + (countd + 1) + " has " + shots[countd] +  " shots and will cost" ) ;
```

Note that array indexes begin at zero, so I've updated `countd` to reflect that.

As a general style point, variables should generally begin with a lower case letter, so you should use `cupsOfCoffee` ideally.

Comment: yea it was a typo mistake, shots also doesnt run, i'll edit this here thanks.

Comment: i tried declaring it out side the loop as my second example, but i am not getting what i want, i am only getting the last value I ENTER for all the cups, as i explained in my post

Comment: Thanks bro ! I got it  working ! Saved my life, lets FINISH THIS CODE :D 
thnak u again man ! CHEERS :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array so that you have a shot count for each cup.

```
int countd;
int[] shots = new int[CupsOfCoffee];
for (countd = 1; countd <= CupsOfCoffee; ++countd) {
    System.out.println("How many coffee shots in cup "+ countd);
    shots[countd - 1] = keyboard.nextInt();
}

for (countd = 1; countd <= CupsOfCoffee; ++countd) {
    System.out.println("cup " + countd + "has" + shots[countd - 1]+  "and will cost");
}
```

Comment: tanks MAN (Y)( appreciate it